# Getting the Out of memory error when displaying full screen image in android

Tags: android, imageview, out-of-memory, android-camera

I have implemented a gridview and full screen image view. Everything works fine, until I do like this. 
1. I'll open my grid view and click on any thumbnail image and display the image in full screen. Then i'll come back to grid view from image view and click on other thumbnail image. If I repeat these steps for 6 times. I'll get a out of memory error when I click on thumbnail image for the 7th time.

I'm using view pager in my image view to scroll the images.

```
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position){
        TouchImageView imageView;

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fullscreen_image, container, false);

        imageView = (TouchImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePaths.get(position), options);
```

checked for the solution in Stackoverflow, I got this solution but getting the same error.

```
        if(bitmap!= null && bitmap.isRecycled()){
                bitmap.recycle();
                bitmap = null;
            }
```

Below was the solution.

```
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }
```

My logcat details.

```
02-20 19:39:40.265  31543-31543/com.android.exampleI/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 100MB to 96MB
02-20 19:39:40.265  31543-31543/com.android.example I/art﹕ GcCauseForAlloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 178(8KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(16KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 92MB/93MB, paused 1.872ms total 20.641ms
02-20 19:39:40.305  31543-31543/com.android.example I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 100MB to 96MB
02-20 19:39:40.305  31543-31543/com.android.example I/art﹕ GcCauseForAlloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 8(8KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 92MB/93MB, paused 9.165ms total 39.789ms
02-20 19:39:40.305  31543-31543/com.android.example I/art﹕ Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 3MB allocation
02-20 19:39:40.337  31543-31543/com.android.example I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 100MB to 96MB
02-20 19:39:40.338  31543-31543/com.android.example I/art﹕ GcCauseForAlloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 7(224B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 92MB/93MB, paused 2.706ms total 32.142ms
02-20 19:39:40.338  31543-31543/com.android.example E/art﹕ Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 3686412 byte allocation with 498496 free bytes"
02-20 19:39:40.355  31543-31543/com.android.example D/skia﹕ --- decoder->decode returned false
02-20 19:39:40.375  31543-31543/com.android.example D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
02-20 19:39:40.408  31543-31543/com.android.example E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.android.example, PID: 31543
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 3686412 byte allocation with 498496 free bytes
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:620)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:376)
            at com.android.example.FullScreenImageAdapter.instantiateItem(FullScreenImageAdapter.java:53)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:837)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1021)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5137)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5137)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5137)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5137)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5137)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1942)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1132)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1321)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1019)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5725)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
```

I have tried with bitmap.samppleSize = 4 and also with 8. Again the same problem and more over my fullscreen image looks blur.

Comment: What size are the bitmaps?

Comment: Each Image size is around 780KB to 850KB.

Comment: Try using the ImageLoader library, it have a better manage of bitmaps and memory.

Comment: (bitmap!= null && bitmap.isRecycled() ) would have to be  bitmap!= null && ! bitmap.isRecycled() ?

Comment: I'm using Picasso to load image in grid view.

Comment: If it happens after several steps may be you got memory leaks

Comment: @sany if I do the change, image is not displaying in image view.

Comment: My logcat doesn't say that I got a memory leak.

Comment: Pls provide a solution and then down vote the question.

Comment: Can anyone help me in solving this.

Comment: What is the bitmap size (height and width) not the file size?  The file size is not relevant.  The RAM required is height x width x 4 bytes.

Comment: I'm using  int width = bitmap.getWidth();
        int height= bitmap.getHeight();   . width is 720 and Height is 1280.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You guys for helping me in finding a solution.

Instead of using a bitmap to decode image show in image view. We can use picasso to load image .

```
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position){
        TouchImageView imageView;

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fullscreen_image, container, false);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(String.valueOf(imagePaths.get(position))));
        imageView = (TouchImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);

        Picasso.with(container.getContext())
                .load(uri)
               .into(imageView);

      container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }
```

This solved my out of memory error. If there is more better may of doing please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put whole size bitmaps in a memory - it to heavy. You should scale it down before. The easiest way to go is to not reinvent the bicycle but go with [Android universal image loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) or [Aquery](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading) library. Both of them contains examples how to do gridview of images.

Comment: Is problem in grid view or displaying a image in full screen?

Comment: Problem in memory leak